# Is there any way to Create Post on Wordpress using Flutter and wordpress REST API

Tags: json, flutter, post, wordpress-rest-api

I want to Create a post on WordPress using REST API, am beginner and stuck at this point, any expert can help please

Heres is My Post upload method.

---

```
void uploadPost() async {
LoginResponseModel loginDetails = await SharedService.loginDetails();
postUploadModelClass = PostUploadModelClass(
  title: Guid(
    rendered: title,
  ),
  sticky: false,
  excerpt: Content(protected: false, rendered: content),
  author: loginDetails.data.id,
  format: Format.STANDARD,
  content: Content(protected: false, rendered: content),
  jetpackFeaturedMediaUrl:
      "https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/14589041-abf52a8d8c.png",
  status: StatusEnum.PUBLISH,
  type: Type.POST,
);

String jsonBody = json.encode(postUploadModelClass.toJson());
print("tytytytytyy${jsonBody}");

Uri url = Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts");
var response = await http.post(
  url,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ${loginDetails.data.token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  },
  body: jsonBody ,
);
print("Test${response.body}");
```

}

am getting this Response

```
I/flutter ( 1559): Test{"code":"empty_content","message":"Content, title, and excerpt are empty.","data":{"status":400}}
```

---

Comment: Have you tried add a breakpoint before your POST is sent, and find out what is in `json.encode(PostUploadModelClass().toJson())`?

Comment: @PeterKoltai i tried but it gives same error , PostUploadMOdelClass is my model class by which I want to send my data

Comment: Edited My question now have a look again @PeterKoltai

Comment: I mean what is the body of the request, `jsonBody`.  Your are getting a 400 in the response status, meaning that the body you send is missing some required data. Also add to you question value of `postUploadModelClass` before `json.encode`. And also you `PostUploadModelClass` definition.